# How Mllib in Spark select variables in logistic regression

Tags: machine-learning, bigdata, logistic-regression, scala, apache-spark

I have a question about MLlib in Spark.(with Scala)

I'm trying to understand how LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS and LogisticRegressionWithSGD work. I usually use SAS or R to do logistic regressions but I now have to do it on Spark to be able to analyze Big Data.

How is the variable selection done? Is there any try of different variable combinations in LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS or LogisticRegressionWithSGD? Something like a test of significance of variable one by one? Or a correlation calculation with the variable of interest? Is there any calculation of BIC, AIC to choose the best model?

Because the model only returns weights and intercept...

How can I understand those Spark functions and compare to what I'm used to with SAS or R ?

Answer (score 4):

First, the spark programming guide for [LogisticRegressionWithSGD](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithSGD) recommends using [L-BFGS](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS) instead, so perhaps focus on the one.  As for variable selection, the model description on the [MLLib page for regressions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-linear-methods.html#logistic-regression) has a nice explanation of how models are constructed and selected, but it does not address variable selection.  This leads me to believe that it considers all variables, and simply chooses the model with the best fit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but now my question is : how does it choose the best model, with which criteria?

Comment: The weights that are returned are an expression of the importance of your variable vector.  The training process trains several combinations of different weights, and tests to see which subset gives the best results:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-linear-methods.html#mathematical-formulation

Answer (score 1):

You could always do a Lasso regression by setting the elastic net parameter to 1:

`val reg = new LogisticRegression()
  .setElasticNetParam(1)`

The Lasso regression penalizes the number of coefficients, so it is indirectly doing variable selection.

See [the help of Spark's Mllib](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-linear-methods.html#linear-least-squares-lasso-and-ridge-regression).